# Converting Shiny code to a modularised Shiny server and UI?

Tags: r, shiny

I have two apps which do the same thing. The first one is incorrect but the second one works.

Its suppose to print to the console the JS cell selected and also `renderText()` the same output to the App.

I can't seem to put the server or ui into a module and correctly call the `ns` for the App to work.

How can I change the second App to a modularised App?

Shiny App which does not works (attempting to put the server into a `ns` module.

```
library(reactable)
library(shiny)

iris = iris %>%
  select(-c(Species))

##############


myModuleServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$irisTABLE = renderReactable({
        reactable(iris,
                  onClick = JS("
                function(rowInfo, colInfo, e) {
                  Shiny.setInputValue('cell_data', colInfo.id + '-' + rowInfo.index)
                }
              "),
                  bordered = TRUE,
                  columns = list(
                    Sepal.Length = colDef(
                      cell = function(value) paste0(format(round(value, 4) * 100), "%")
                    )
                  ),
                  defaultColDef = colDef(
                    align = "center",
                    headerStyle = list(background = "#12a09a"),
                    cell = function(value) format(round(value, 4) * 100)
                  )
        )
      })

      output$cellDATA = renderText({
        if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
          row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
          paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1])
        }
      })


      observeEvent(input$cell_data, {
        if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
          row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
          print(paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1]))
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

##############

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactable::reactableOutput("irisTABLE"),
  textOutput("cellDATA")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  myModuleServer("myNAMESPACE")

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Shiny App which works:

```
library(reactable)
library(shiny)

iris = iris %>%
  select(-c(Species))

ui <- fluidPage(
  reactable::reactableOutput("irisTABLE"),
  textOutput("cellDATA")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$irisTABLE = renderReactable({
    reactable(iris,
              onClick = JS("
                function(rowInfo, colInfo, e) {
                  Shiny.setInputValue('cell_data', colInfo.id + '-' + rowInfo.index)
                }
              "),
              bordered = TRUE,
              columns = list(
                Sepal.Length = colDef(
                  cell = function(value) paste0(format(round(value, 4) * 100), "%")
                )
              ),
              defaultColDef = colDef(
                align = "center",
                headerStyle = list(background = "#12a09a"),
                cell = function(value) format(round(value, 4) * 100)
              )
    )
  })

  output$cellDATA = renderText({
    if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
      row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
      paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1])
    }
  })


  observeEvent(input$cell_data, {
    if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
      row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
      print(paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1]))
    }
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move your UI code to a module UI. Second, you have to set your `cell_data` in the module namespace, i.e. in you JS code you have to add the value from `NS(id, 'cell_data')` instead of just `'cell_data'` :

```
library(reactable)
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris %>%
  select(-c(Species))

myModuleUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    reactable::reactableOutput(ns("irisTABLE")),
    textOutput(ns("cellDATA"))
  )
}

myModuleServer <- function(id, data) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      output$irisTABLE <- renderReactable({
        reactable(iris2,
          onClick = JS( paste0("function(rowInfo, colInfo, e) {
                  Shiny.setInputValue('", NS(id, 'cell_data'), "', colInfo.id + '-' + rowInfo.index)
                }
              ")),
          bordered = TRUE,
          columns = list(
            Sepal.Length = colDef(
              cell = function(value) paste0(format(round(value, 4) * 100), "%")
            )
          ),
          defaultColDef = colDef(
            align = "center",
            headerStyle = list(background = "#12a09a"),
            cell = function(value) format(round(value, 4) * 100)
          )
        )
      })

      output$cellDATA <- renderText({
        if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
          row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
          paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1])
        }
      })


      observeEvent(input$cell_data, {
        if (!is.null(input$cell_data)) {
          row_col <- strsplit(input$cell_data, "-")
          print(paste0("The cell selected is in row ", row_col[[1]][2], " and column ", row_col[[1]][1]))
        }
      })
    }
  )
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  myModuleUI("myNAMESPACE")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  myModuleServer("myNAMESPACE")
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looking at some of my other code I almost had it but I was missing the point of wrapping the `ns` inside the `JS` code. Thanks for helping :)